# Should I use Dr. Racket for learning Scheme?

Tags: functional-programming

I've been fiddling with software development for a couple of years and in trying to get into the gist of things I came across SICP, which uses Scheme.

Basically what I want to do at this stage is to store exercise/test .scm files for study. Should I use Emac or Dr. Racket ? Or none of those?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this is more appropriate for [cseducators.se].

Comment: I suggest Emacs: Then whatever you learn you can **immediately** try out with respect to text manipulation via a slight jump to ELisp ;-)